# How to override Alamofire SessionManager to modify response in order to add headers?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlcache

So, I'm using Alamofire to make some HTTP requests and I'm trying to use the caching policy but the server doesn't have the "Cache-Control" flag in its headers. So I want to add this flag using the session manager [delegate method](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#session-delegate) `dataTaskWillCacheResponse` based on this [answer here.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2210)

In order to do that I wanted to create a class with a static shared instance (*I don't want to create a global variable on AppDelegate. I think it's not a good practice*) of SessionManager and in this class override the delegate method but I can't do.

Here is my code:

```
public class Manager: SessionDelegate {
    var manager: SessionManager?
    weak var sessionDelegate: SessionDelegate?
    override init() {
        super.init()
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.urlCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 35
        self.manager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        self.manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        self.manager?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

On `self.manager.delegate = self` I get the error: Cannot assign to property: 'delegate' is a 'let' constant

I'm relatively new in Swift and Alamofire. What am I doing wrong? And how could I achieve what I'm trying to do?

**Edit:**
I saw that I wasn't able to create a singleton but I was able to use a shared instance and override the methods. Check the answer below

Comment: Any particular reason for the singleton? You don't need one. `SessionManager` creates and assigns its delegate during its own `init()`

Comment: No one. I thought this would be a good solution and I would be able to override the delegate methods in the singleton class.

Comment: You can already override dataTaskWillCacheResponse it's an open var. See [Overriding Closures](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#override-closures) in Alamofire Docs

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm playing with. I think I could do it but I think I can't edit the cachedResponse.

Answer (score 1):

After researching more, I found some things:
1 - [Advanced usage override closures](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#session-delegate)
2 - [Found this answer that creates a Session Manager](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1684#issuecomment-252547572)
3 - [Found this solution](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1176#issuecomment-208959441) that adds headers on my response in the `dataTaskWillCacheResponse` delegate method.

This is my solution:

```
class MyService {
    static let shared = MyService()

    //The manager with the cache policy
    private let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 35
        return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    init() {
        let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = manager.delegate
        //Overriding delegate to add headers
        delegate.dataTaskWillCacheResponseWithCompletion = { session, datatask, cachedResponse, completion in
            let response = cachedResponse.response  as! HTTPURLResponse
            var headers = response.allHeaderFields as! [String: String]
            print(headers.keys.contains("Cache-Control"))
            headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=30"
            let modifiedResponse = HTTPURLResponse(
                url: response.url!,
                statusCode: response.statusCode,
                httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1",
                headerFields: headers)

            let modifiedCachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(
                response: modifiedResponse!,
                data: cachedResponse.data,
                userInfo: cachedResponse.userInfo,
                storagePolicy: cachedResponse.storagePolicy)
            completion(modifiedCachedResponse)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Just call the same URL and if the response is cached it will return it.

Comment: It will return the cached response if the max-age has not expired